# what does this error mean in min gw?

Tags: c, mingw

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.tex
t+0xd2): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is my source code and is there when I am trying to comlpile a program. This is the command that I am typing in `C:\Users\Kyle Mitchell\Documents>gcc program09.c -o program09.exe`

```
#include <stdio.h>
void displayInstructions(void);
float getRadius(void);
float calculateCircumference(float);
void displayResults(float);

int mian(void)
{
 float radius;
 float circumference;
 displayInstructions();
 radius = getRadius();
 circumference = calculateCircumference(radius);
 displayResults(circumference);
 return 0;
}

void displayInstructions(void)
{
   printf("This program will calculate the circumference of a circle.\n");
}

float getRadius(void)
{
  float radius;

  printf("Please enter the raidus:\n");
  printf("> ");
  scanf("%f", &radius);
  return radius;
}

float calculateCircumference(float radius)
{
 float PI = 3.1415;
   return PI * radius * 2;
}

void displayResults(float circumference)
{
   printf("\n\n\n\n\n");
   printf("==============================\n");
   printf("= PROGRAM RESULTS =\n");
   printf("= circumference: %.2f\n", circumference);
}
```

Comment: by the way, major kudos for including the error message and command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program must contain a main or a WinMain in order to be a valid windows program. You have a mian. It complains about WinMain because that is the normal way for a windows program. However, mingw should be fine if you just spell main correctly.

Answer (score 1):

replace `mian` with `main`